# question on yum

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

Ill give an example on the problem that I am having.

I have a package, lets name is pack ver. 1 currently on the yum server, then I put an updated one "pack ver. 2", after reindexing the yum server, I tested it.

doing a "yum clean all && yum search pack" it will say that I have ver. 1
but doing a "yum install pack" it will say that it will install ver. 2

My question is, how come when doing the search it will only see ver. 1 and not ver. 2? This will confuses our user when they are doing the search.

Comment: What does `yum list available` say?

Comment: have you tried yum clean all; yum clean dbcache; yum clean metadata; yum -y update ?  - also make sure you recreate the source repo (delete the old files and use createrepo)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so much an answer as a correction.  If you want to see what specific versions of a package are available, you'll be much more successful if you use `yum info`, which will show you the latest installed and the latest available.  `yum search` won't differentiate between installed and available versions, because it's purpose is to search for package names, not versions.

You can also use any of the following:

```
yum list installed pack
yum list available pack
yum list pack
```

You can also always get a list of commands by typing `man yum` at the prompt.

Hope this helps!